# Compare elements of two lists in java

Tags: java

I have two lists where some information is stored. Elements of first list are extracted from a DB (they are the ingredients of recipes), in the second list some favourite ingredients are stored. I want to compare both lists and when the ingredients match I want to add 1 to a sum.
My problem is when I parse the first list the ingredients are compared with the second list, but in my first list I have elements that are not made from one string( one element has 2-3 words), and when I compare the lists, are compared only the last elements, aren't compared the components of elements.

First list :

```
[200 grame fusilli cu legume (spanac si mere);
200 grame smantana 12%; 
50 grame iaurt; 
50 grame cascaval afumat; 
1/2 lingurite mustar; 
doi catei de usturoi sau o lingurita de usturoi deshidratat; 
o lingur? ulei de masline; 
mere]
```

Second list:

```
[afine, almette, alune, alune, albus de ou de gaina, alune, andive, mere]
```

And my result is

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

We can saw that word "mere" is met twice in first list an once in second list,but the result is 0. How can I resolve the problem?

Here is my java code:

```
rs=ps.executeQuery();                           
while( rs.next()){
String nrRet = rs.getString("Ingrediente");          
firstList.add(nrRet);                  
}
System.out.println(firstList);
Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
rs1 = st1.executeQuery("Select Nume from ingredientplacut where Id_user = '24'");


 while( rs1.next()){
   String nrRet1 = rs1.getString("Nume");
   secondList.add(nrRet1);                                
   }

   System.out.println(secondList);      
   ArrayList<String> al3= new ArrayList<String>();
   for (String temp : firstList)
   al3.add(secondList.contains(temp) ? "Yes" : "No");
   System.out.println(al3);


   ArrayList<Integer> al4= new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for (String temp2 : firstList)
   al4.add(secondList.contains(temp2) ? 1 : 0);
   System.out.println(al4);
```

My output is:

```
First list : [200 grame fusilli cu legume (spanac si **mere**);
200 grame smantana 12%; 
50 grame iaurt; 
50 grame cascaval afumat; 
1/2 lingurite mustar; 
doi catei de usturoi sau o lingurita de usturoi deshidratat; 
o lingur? ulei de masline; 
**mere**]
Second list: [afine, almette, alune, alune, albus de ou de gaina, alune, andive, mere]
```

And My result is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` instead of `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Why is your first list separated by semi-colons whereas your second list is separated by commas? I'm asking because I'm uncertain what your actual inputs are. Printing a list usually formats it with commas. I suspect there's something strange happening here. Especially since your input list has 8 elements but your result has 9.

Comment: Informations are extracted from a db and in the table after every line are inserted semi-colons,in the second list aren't semi-colons because in the table is present only one data not more like in the first array,

Comment: Try this: `for (String ingredient : firstList) System.out.printf("\"%s\": %s%n", ingredient, secondList.contains(ingredient));` What's the output?

Comment: "200 grame fusilli cu legume (afine si mere);
200 grame smantana 12%;
50 grame iaurt;
50 grame cascaval afumat ;
1/2 lingurite mustar;
doi catei de usturoi sau o lingurita de usturoi deshidratat;
afine;
mere;
patrunjel; 
piper;
sare.": false  

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

not   [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

Comment: This demonstrates that your list of ingredients doesn't contain each ingredient in a separate list element. The list contains one element, which contains all your ingredients in a single String. So what you need to do is split this string into separate ingredients.

Comment: Yes, the ingredients are stored into one single String.
How can I split it into separate ingredients?

Comment: [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 1):

You can simple add an **Inner for loop** to check the content.Your problem is an element from **List2** can contain inside an element of **list1** rather than being exactly same.For e.g list1 has "200 grame fusilli cu legume (spanac si mere)" and list 2 has only "mere".This can be solved by adding another inner for loop.

See the below small code here I have fixed the contents of "**al3**".U can do the same for **al4**

```
 for (String temp : firstList)
       {
           boolean isTrue=false;
           for(String temp2:secondList)
           {
               if(temp.contains(temp2))
               {
                   isTrue=true;
                   break;
               }
           }
           if(isTrue)
               al3.add("YES");
           else
               al3.add("NO");

       }
```

For your input sets code for al4 will be :

```
for (String temp2 : secondList) {
        boolean isTrue = false;
        for (String temp : firstList) {
            if (temp.contains(temp2)) {
                isTrue = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isTrue)
            al4.add(1);
        else
            al4.add(0);
    }
```

As list2 element can be inside list1 element I have customized the code accordingly.You can customize your code according to input patterns.

Comment: I have updated the answer.Have a look .my code just will give you an idea how to do it.Its difficult to give the exact generic solution without knowing the whole scenario. You can also try using "String Tokenizer" to split the entries if reqd

Comment: Yes, It helped me, the problem is almost solved.Thank you very much!

Comment: Most Welcome buddy

Comment: Also this is done for one of the list of ingredients.
I extract the ingredients from a db ,and the above code is done for all the recipe ingredients,I want to do this for every time I parse the list of recipes.

 while( rs.next()){
         String nrRet = rs.getString("Ingrediente");
        // request.setAttribute("Ehealth", datalist);
       
        firstList.add(nrRet);
        }

I want to be done for every time I parse one row of table of the db,not like now after all is parsed

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using [CollectionUtils.intersection](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#intersection(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable)) ?

This will perform a match against two sets (you may want to look at splitting your strings from the first set) and give you all elements that exist in both.